# Why is Internet Explorer 8 still accepting cookies?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cookies

In my Internet Options -> Privacy, I have the setting set to Block All Cookies.

However, when I run my website which will attempt to write out and then read a cookie to test whether the user has cookies enabled, the cookie is there.

Should Internet Explorer have allowed it to be created and then read? Isn't this privacy setting supposed to apply to all zones? (I'm running the website on localhost).

Comment: Hmm. IE8 won't even let me to set cookies on `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow have a feeling that your use of 127.0.0.1 will allow cookies by default, no matter what your cookies settings, because you aren't actually accessing a remote network. Have you tried different browsers?

With that, you should use Firefox or Chrome... they are much better browsers. :)

Comment: I only use IE when I have to test certain things. Otherwise I do use FireFox :P Also FireFox and Chrome seem to work fine.